# AngularJS Animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I am trying to implement angular js animations when the view changes in my app. For some reason I can get no animation at all.

Here is my app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngAnimate',
  'categoryControllers'
]);

//--------------------Controllers----------------------------//

var categoryControllers = angular.module('categoryControllers', []);

categoryControllers.controller('DataController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams',    function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('json/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.project = data;
    $scope.currentCat = $routeParams.cat;
    $scope.currentEx = $routeParams.exId;
  });

}]);

//---------------------Routing----------------------------//

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
    controller: 'DataController'
  })
  .when('/splash', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/splash.html',
    controller: 'DataController'
  })
  .when('/:cat', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
    controller: 'DataController'
  });
}]);
```

And my CSS:

```
.animate-enter, 
.animate-leave
{ 
    -webkit-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 300ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
} 

.animate-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}

.animate-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.animate-leave.animate-leave-active{
    left: -100%;
}
```

And finally how I implemented it in my HTML, I only implemented it in the index.html as opposed to the partials.

```
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="animate" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How about the animate class? <div class="ng-scope animate" ng-view></div>. And I don't see any call to 'myApp' (<body ng-app="myApp">), or did you leave it out intentionnaly ?

Comment: Oops.. I meant to put 'animate' class there instead of 'ng-scope'. Copy and paste fail, I corrected it above. And I did leave the call to myApp out when I cropped my code for simplicity sake on the question.

Comment: Sorry, wrong window. BRB.

Comment: Did you try adding ng-enter and ng-leave, as shown in the voted answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272843/sliding-between-route-transition-angularjs

Comment: where is your code for the actual animations?

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately a no go.

Comment: Code for animations is the beginning part of CSS displayed above

Comment: @Bonatoc There was a combination of things wrong. However what you proposed ended up being the culprit but I also had to call it using the following: <div class="animation" ng-view>

Answer (score 0):

you should use ng-animate="'animate'" instead of class='animate'

Comment: From what I have been reading it says that the ng-animate directive is deprecated since version 1.2 and to use classes instead as it is now built in. But I very possibly could be wrong. ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465253/ng-repeat-animation-not-working